# Is the Drill Through (or Drill Down) functionality for RDLC report only available for web applications?

Tags: windows, rdlc, drilldown, drillthrough

We have several Crystal Reports that are used in a Windows Form application that we are re-creating using RDLC. One of the reports needs the ability to drill through (or down) to more detailed data. I've followed several examples (mostly for SSRS) to enable the drill through functionality in the RDLC report but I can never get it to work. Its like the drill through logic is being ignored. I never get the "hand" to appear. I've even tried using "Go to URL" for the action and that doesn't work.

Is this functionality only available for SSRS or web applications?